# Slaying the Dragon JS

Tags: javascript, variables, while-loop, boolean

I was assigned to write the following code:

```js
var slaying = true;
var youHit= Math.floor(Math.random()*2); 
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);  
var totalDamage = 3; 

while (slaying){
   
    if(youHit === 1){
        console.log("Congratulations!, You hit your first Dragon.");
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;
        if(totalDamage >= 4){
                console.log('You slew the dragon'); 
            }else if(totalDamage < 4){
                youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
                }
        slaying = false;
        }else if(youHit === 0){
            console.log("Try again, the dragon defeated you");
             slaying = false;
            }
    
    }
```

This code runs but at the end I get an output of False,

Can someone please help me understand if this is coming from the slaying variable, or if this is a result os one of the if statements? I don't understand whay it appears on the console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example seems to work.

Comment: If you want to understand this code, you should probably just go to the codecademy tutorial that this was ripped from: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-mrTNH-6VIZ9/0/1?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Comment: @Cole9350 Thanks for your response. This was a task from code academy and I coded this but still needed some clarification. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the code returns true or false depends on this line of code:

```
var youHit= Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
```

`Math.random()` gets a random number between 0 and 1. If the random number is anything over .5, you get true, otherwise, you get false. This code will randomly select a number every time it runs. You can verify this by setting:

```
var youHit = .9
```

or

```
var youHit = .1
```